# Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Spring cloud 2023.0.0 | Spring Cloud API Gateway not starting on openshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have deployed spring cloud API gateway on kubernetes environment. Below are the versions which I am using

> **Spring Boot : 3.2.0 Spring Cloud : 2023.0.0**

While booting up the application it is stuck. I have enabled the logs at trace level and found after discovering all the services, the application is stuck. The last log I am able to see is "RouteDefination ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_{SERVICE_NAME} applying {pattern={SERVICE_NAME/**}}"

The same code was working with Spring Cloud 2022.0.2 without any issue.
After searching over the internet, I found to enable `spring.main.cloud-platform=KUBERNETES` but it doesn't helped at all.

According to the breaking changes of 2022.0.3 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2022.0-Release-Notes changes has been made in Spring Cloud Kubernetes component.

Can any one help with the configuration which is needed to be done to make it work.

I have enabled the property `spring.main.cloud-platform=KUBERNETES` and still the issue is persisting.

Expecting to boot up the API Gateway with all the service discovery.

Comment: This issue is tracked at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/1535